# Convert a text file with items seperated by newlines to a list in python

Tags: python

I have a file with usernames, each username is on a new line, im trying to convert it to a list with python, how do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre] of your code and ask a question about specific problem with your code.

Comment: @0x5453 ive tried to do "usernames = list(map(str.split, f.read().split('\n\n')))" but it gives me a list which is only 1 item in length, ive atached an example [here](https://fileportal.org/CAA4jabQ1GESRGcSDAGLxLAZyrmIfxtXBLtEU8KuEOsxTg)

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Why do you split with two newline characters?

Comment: If you open your file with `with open (your_filename_here) as f:` then it's a simple `usernames = [line.strip() for line in f]` to read everything and to strip spaces and newline characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a file with usernames in the below format.

users.txt

```
user1    
user2    
user3    
user4
```

sample python code is:

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
     lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]


print(type(lines))
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
#read s.txt file
fp=open("s.txt","r")
s=fp.read()
usernamesarr=s.split("\n")
print(usernamesarr)
```

output:

```
[naveenkumar,sethu,logan]
```

s.txt

```
naveenkumar
sethu
logan
```

Think I have understood your question.

Comment: this is too complicated. and it will give you strings. it cant give you list of variables as output

Comment: might be.......

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file
- use the function `x.readlines()`
- DONE!

Example:

```py
file = open("r", "usernames.txt")
listofusernames = file.readlines()
file.close()
print(listofusernames)
```

And the output will be:

```py
["User1\n", "User2\n", "User3\n"]
```

If you don't want the `\n`s there after most of the elements, you need

```py
rep = []
for x in listofusernames:
    rep.append(x.replace("\n", ""))
print(list(rep))
```

so the full code will be:

```py
file = open("r", "usernames.txt")
listofusernames = file.readlines()
file.close()
rep = []
for x in listofusernames:
    rep.append(x.replace("\n", ""))
print(list(rep))
```

And now the output will be correct, sorry for my error

Comment: You forgot the trailing newline.

Comment: Sorry? I have used this code like a hundred times, and its working fine

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, the list is created but there is a "\n" at the end of each element inside the list, how do i remove it?

Comment: @BallaBotond That's obviously wrong. There's a newline at the end of each string. How could this even run if you start with an error in the first line (switched parameters)?